# Very small file size PDF's from InDesign, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export, file-size

I am creating a 12 page booklet, 120 x 180mm. All pages are text only except for the front cover which includes a PSD background and a Illustrator vector logo. When I export using the press quality preset in InDesign my file size is just over 1mb. Is this normal? Or am I doing something wrong? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the resolution of the `psd` background and its contents, this could very well be right. Text and vectors don't take up a lot of space by themselves, especially when optimised as in a `pdf`. If the visible parts of your `psd` happen to lend themselves well to compression, you may just have a perfectly fine file.

One thing you could check is the `psd`'s actual resolution. You can find this in the `Links` palette in InDesign by selecting the line with the *.psd and twirling open the triangle at the bottom of the palette:

[image]

In the list of data that appears, check `effective PPI`. If that is 300 or higher, you are fine.

[image]

Comment: my PPI is 300! Thanks a lot for clearing this up for me I feel a lot better now!